# Multiple function invocations in javascript ie combine(foo)(bar)

Tags: javascript, function, invocation

I have seen in the past that you can do something like this:

```
function combine(arg1){
   return function(arg2){
      return (arg1 + arg2);
   };
}
combine("foo")("bar");
```

And the result will be "foobar".

You can of course do something like:

```
(function(x){
    return function(y){
       return x+y;
    };
})(2)(3);
```

With the result of 5.

I am simply wondering what this is called. I think I saw a small video of Crockford that I can't seem to find, I am sure it was on the Good Parts, that briefly talked about this. I also have the book and I can't see it in there.

It seems like just another way to invoke a function and control the scope of the variables.

Comment: "Chaining", maybe? I feel like it's something else though, although "chaining" *should* apply to the invocations.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are looking for the word [Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying)

Comment: You know, I was thinking _currying_, but convinced myself OP was asking about the double invocation specifically. But _currying_ is absolutely correct.

Comment: FYI: [Page 43](http://books.google.com/books?id=PXa2bby0oQ0C&q=curried#v=onepage&q=currying&f=false) in the book.

Answer (score 1):

Rchristiani, the video where Crockford references a function that adds from two invocations can be found on YouTube. It's part of a FrontEndMasters.com workshop series.

Test Your Knowledge of Function Scope with Douglas Crockford: http://youtu.be/hRJrp17WnOE

Crockford's site contains a copy of an excellent, and mind-blowing, breakdown of Currying. (I'm not sure who the original author is.) It shows examples of multiple invocations.

http://www.crockford.com/javascript/www_svendtofte_com/code/curried_javascript/index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to the ability of the inner function to access the variables from the outer function, this is called a closure.

You can read up closures here:
[How do JavaScript closures work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work)

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is the [Currying](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying), or [Partial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying#Contrast_with_partial_function_application) (it depends if the functions takes more than two arguments or not).

You can actually do that also with [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), from ES5 specs. For instance:

```
function sum(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}

var sum5 = sum.bind(null, 5);

console.log(sum5(10)); // 15
```